# trying to use post request and response using retrofit android but error like org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, retrofit

```
Request: {
  "hotel_id": "901"
}

Response: {
  "status": "Success",
  "msg": "Success",
  "hotelcontacts": [{
    "hotel_id": "905",
    "hotel_manger_no": "7868546769",
    "hotel_manger_email": "manger2@gmail.com",
    "hotel_receptionist_no": "9023984567",
    "hotel_receptionist_mail": "receptionist2@gmail.com"
  }]
}

PostInterface api = retrofit.create(PostInterface.class);

Call < String > call = api.getUserLogin("901");

call.enqueue(new Callback < String > () {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call < String > call, Response < String > response) {
    Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());
    //Toast.makeText()
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
      if (response.body() != null) {
        Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());

        String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();
        parseLoginData(jsonresponse);

      } else {
        Log.i("onEmptyResponse", "Returned empty response"); //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Nothing returned",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call < String > call, Throwable t) {

  }
});

}

public void parseLoginData(String response) {

  try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("true")) {

      JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hotelcontacts");
      for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);
        firstName = dataobj.getString("hotel_manger_no");
        hobby = dataobj.getString("hotel_manger_email");
      }

      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HobbyActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}

/onSuccess: {"status":"Success","msg":"Success","hotelcontacts":null}
```

its hotelcontacts are getting null. its not getting actual data. please help me

Comment: Please check my updated answer - @surya kommana

Answer (score 0):

Create two POJO Model Class

```
public class ResponseModel {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("msg")
    @Expose
    private String msg;

    @SerializedName("hotelcontacts")
    @Expose
    private List<Hotelcontact> hotelcontacts = null;

    public String getStatus() {
         return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
         this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
         return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public List<Hotelcontact> getHotelcontacts() {
        return hotelcontacts;
    }

    public void setHotelcontacts(List<Hotelcontact> hotelcontacts) {
        this.hotelcontacts = hotelcontacts;
    }

}
```

Create another model for subarray

```
public class Hotelcontact {

    @SerializedName("hotel_id")
    @Expose
    private String hotelId;

    @SerializedName("hotel_manger_no")
    @Expose
    private String hotelMangerNo;

    @SerializedName("hotel_manger_email")
    @Expose
    private String hotelMangerEmail;

    @SerializedName("hotel_receptionist_no")
    @Expose
    private String hotelReceptionistNo;

    @SerializedName("hotel_receptionist_mail")
    @Expose
    private String hotelReceptionistMail;

    public String getHotelId() {
       return hotelId;
    }

    public void setHotelId(String hotelId) {
       this.hotelId = hotelId;
    }

    public String getHotelMangerNo() {
       return hotelMangerNo;
    }

    public void setHotelMangerNo(String hotelMangerNo) {
       this.hotelMangerNo = hotelMangerNo;
    }

    public String getHotelMangerEmail() {
       return hotelMangerEmail;
    }

    public void setHotelMangerEmail(String hotelMangerEmail) {
       this.hotelMangerEmail = hotelMangerEmail;
    }

    public String getHotelReceptionistNo() {
       return hotelReceptionistNo;
    }

    public void setHotelReceptionistNo(String hotelReceptionistNo) {
       this.hotelReceptionistNo = hotelReceptionistNo;
    }

    public String getHotelReceptionistMail() {
       return hotelReceptionistMail;
    }

    public void setHotelReceptionistMail(String hotelReceptionistMail) {
      this.hotelReceptionistMail = hotelReceptionistMail;
    }

}
```

Use

```
Call<ResponseModel> call = api.getUserLogin("901");
```

Instead of

```
Call<String> call = api.getUserLogin("901");


firstName = response.body().getHotelcontacts().get(0).getHotelMangerNo();
hobby = response.body().getHotelcontacts().get(0).getHotelMangerEmail();
```

Comment: getting error in this line: body response.body.getHotelcontacts().get(0).getHotelMangerNo(); can you please explain more